# Show when the inequality for matrix-vector multiplication for the 2 norm is an equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number, singular-values

I am asked to show for *which vectors* the inequality $||Ax|| \le ||x||||A|| $ is an *equality*.

My intuition tells me that this happens when $x$ is in the direction of the right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value of A.  Because, then that happens, given the SVD of A as  $A=U\Sigma V^*$, then we can say that $Av_1=\sigma_1u_1$, where the subscript 1 on $u$ and $v$, denotes that it is the vector corresponding to the first column of $U$ and $V$, respectively.

Because, we can take the norm of both sides and get the following:

$||Av_1||=||\sigma_1u_1||=\sigma_1||u_1||=||A||||u_1||$,

and, since $U$ and $V$ have orthonormal columns, we know that $||u_1||=||v_1||=1$, which means we can substitute and get :

$||Av_1||=||A||||v_1||$

And hence this is an equality when the vector $x$ is the right singular vector corresponding to the largest singular value.

Question:  is the above logic correct?  The reason I am unsure, is because if $||Av_1||=||A||||v_1||$, and $||v_1||$ has norm 1, then that would mean $||Av_1||=||A||$.

thanks.

related [Find a vector pair $(b,δb)$ for which $\dfrac{\|δx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}=k_2(A)\dfrac{\|δb\|_2}{\|b\|_2}$ holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440257/find-a-vector-pair-b-%CE%B4b-for-which-dfrac-%CE%B4x-2-x-2-k-2a-dfrac?rq=1)